# Access the camera on flutter webview

Tags: flutter, dart

I have web Page to Show user camera, how I can access the camera on the flutter webview?

I try to do that with this URL "https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/" but return getUserMedia error: NotAllowedError

Answer (score 17):

You can try my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview).

To request permissions about the camera and microphone, you can use the [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) plugin.

Also, it has the `androidOnPermissionRequest` event for Android, that is an event fired when the WebView is requesting permission to access the specified resources (that is the Android native [WebChromeClient.onPermissionRequest event](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient#onPermissionRequest(android.webkit.PermissionRequest))).

An example of using WebRTC that works on Android:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Permission.camera.request();
  await Permission.microphone.request();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: InAppWebViewPage()
    );
  }
}

class InAppWebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InAppWebViewPageState createState() => new _InAppWebViewPageState();
}

class _InAppWebViewPageState extends State<InAppWebViewPage> {
  InAppWebViewController _webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("InAppWebView")
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: InAppWebView(
                      initialUrl: "https://appr.tc/r/158489234",
                      initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                        crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                          mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
                          debuggingEnabled: true,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                        _webViewController = controller;
                      },
                      androidOnPermissionRequest: (InAppWebViewController controller, String origin, List<String> resources) async {
                        return PermissionRequestResponse(resources: resources, action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
                      }
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]))
    );
  }
}
```

This example uses the room `158489234` on https://appr.tc/, that is a video chat demo app based on WebRTC (https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc).
To get it work, you need to set the option `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture` to `false`.

Also, you need to add these permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIDEO_CAPTURE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUDIO_CAPTURE" />
```

Comment: @MadMan for which platform? On iOS it won't work (see https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/200), otherwise open an issue to the plugin repository with all useful information and errors you are getting

Comment: It worked well in Android. Do you know which permission I need to open the dialog box to select a file or an image from Android camera?

Comment: I've used this HTML code to get it working `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>`

Comment: what about iOS?

Comment: @LorenzoPichilli - How would I be able to request client authorizations when a client attempts to upload documents instead of asking in the beginning? (Please see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66565247/how-can-i-ask-for-user-permissions-when-user-tries-to-upload-file-in-mobile-appl)

Comment: @LorenzoPichilli Some of the code in your snippet is out of date, could you please update it? Thanks

Comment: Could you share the full code please. Also its not up to date. Im trying the similar program it does not even resolve without error. @LorenzoPichilli

Comment: Hey, i couldn't get this to work at https://webcam-test.com/

Comment: I never see permission access dialog..

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
final WebViewController controller = WebViewController.fromPlatformCreationParams(params, onPermissionRequest: (resources) async {
          return resources.grant();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the camera in a WebView you should take care of the following:

1. Grant camera access before opnening the webview (This can be done through [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package)
2. Properly initialize you WebViewController, be sure to **await** for all the async methods like `await controller.setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted);`
3. For IOS you must also provide some platform specific parameters using the `WebKitWebViewControllerCreationParams` class of the [webview_flutter_wkwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_wkwebview) package (See the example below)
4. Grant `onPermissionRequest` to controller (See the example below)

Your controller should look similar to this, and you may use a `FutureBuilder` to initialize it before launching your WebView:

```
Future<WebViewController> _getController() async {
late final PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams params;
params = WebViewPlatform.instance is WebKitWebViewPlatform
    ? WebKitWebViewControllerCreationParams(
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true, mediaTypesRequiringUserAction: const <PlaybackMediaTypes>{})
    : const PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams();

final controller = WebViewController.fromPlatformCreationParams(
  params,
  onPermissionRequest: (request) {
    request.grant();
  },
);
await controller.setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted);
await controller.loadRequest(Uri.parse( "Your url" ));

return controller;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, was trying to run a Zoom meeting script in Webview as the Zoom meeting SDK plugin is outdated, had this problem with mic and camera permissions, and the plugin's documentation didn't mention this resource handling part (or at least I missed it).